# How does an element-based Chakra release work?

Tags: naruto

Only a few specific people are able to release elements across their entire body to form Chakra modes of that nature. Examples being the Raikage and Kakuzu. The 3rd and 4th Raikage were able to pass Lightning Release across their entire bodies while Kakuzu could do the same with earth style.

What I'm trying to understand is why the Lightning release that the 3rd and 4th Raikage used never seemed to affect or harm them in any way. I'm asking this because During Sasuke vs Deidra, Sasuke did Lightning Release on his entire body and he took a lot of damage. But on the other hand, the 4th and 5th Raikage's could do this without any problems from coming in contact with the lightning.

Is there some kinda explanation as to why that is? I'm thinking that those 2 probably had a lot of immunity to lightning, but nothing like that has ever been mentioned before.

*PS: All forms of Kekkai Genkai and Jinchuuriki are excluded from this conversation*

Comment: I think Raikage use lightning style similar to chakra cloak which enhances mussel moment and reaction time. In Sasuke case he is using the lightning style to diffuse C_0 bomb which invaded his body at cellular level hence took damage.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy: the Raikages use the Lightning Release as a cloak to increase their physical prowess when using Taijutsu or using any movements.

Meanwhile, Sasuke uses a Lightning Release technique like Chidori to attack himself to disintegrate the C0 Bomb that is already inside his body. When using Chidori, Chidori's lightning happens only outside the body, not inside. In order to disintegrate the C0 Bomb, Sasuke must channel his Chidori's lightning to all of his body including inside. Even though Sasuke is able to use Lightning Cloak Chakra Mode, it also happens only outside the body, not inside. So Sasuke must attack himself with Chidori to channel the lightning all over his body.